# On the greatest norm element of weakly compact set

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $K\subset X$ be a nonempty weakly compact set. I would like to know if there exists a point $u_0\in K$ such that $\|u_0\|\geq \|u\|$ for all $u\in K$.
Thank you for all kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For instance the set $\bigl\{{n\over n+1}e_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\Bigr\}\cup\{0\}$, where $e_n$ is the standard $n$'th unit vector is weakly compact in $\ell_2$, but has no element of maximal norm.

Comment: Thanks @David Mitra for your nice counterexample.